# Split a string into an array where each string uses single quotes

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

In JavaScript I am trying to solve this code war problem but every time I test it, the test run fails because my return array is returning this over what's expected

Expected:

```
'[[14,"a"],[1,"b"],[41,"a"],[1,"c"]]'
```

instead got:

```
[[14, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [41, 'a'], [1, 'c']]
```

I noticed that my `str.split` is returning this as an array  `["a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", …]`

Basically I realized that if I can return the split `str` into single quotes it might fix the expected return how can I go about this.

```js
var compress = function(str) {
  let strArr = str.split('')
  let counter = 1
  let rtnArr = []
  console.log(strArr)

  const strMap = strArr.map((val, idx) => {
    if (val === (strArr[idx + 1])) counter += 1
    else {
      rtnArr.push([counter, val])
      counter = 1
    }
  })
  //  console.log(rtnArr)
  return rtnArr
}
```

Comment: If you want it as a string, use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: If you are asking about `'a'` vs `"a"`: There is no difference between those strings.

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you for the response, That I know but for some odd reason the codewar test is expecting [[14, 'a'], [1, 'b'], [41, 'a'], [1, 'c']] but my split string returns and array with double quotes im just trying to match it as close as possible in order to complete the challenge

Comment: Thank you @Barmar

Comment: Then it depends on how codwars is comparing the values. If they expect a stringified form of the whole value, the `JSON.stringify` should help, as Barmer mentioned. If they do a deep equality test then it wouldn't matter because given a string value you cannot determine how it was created (single or double quoted string literal, string concatenation, etc).

Comment: @FelixKling Thats what I was thinking I wonder why its not passing but I'll give it another shot thank you.